# Zend 2 - is tableGateway producing safe queries from sql injection?

Tags: zend-framework2, sql-injection

I was trying to search for information, but so far cannot see. Also checked in the documentation but did not see.

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html

So are my queries safe? For example

```
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(['email' => $email]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.

You can try the following code to check if the generated SQL statement is safe.

```
$sql = $this->tableGateway->getSql();
$select = $sql->select()->where(array("email" => $someDirtyInputHere));
// you can execute the query using  $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

// output query
echo $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
exit;
```